# Why is it easier to turn the front wheels of a car (without power steering) when it's moving than when it's stationary?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics, friction, rotation

Why is it easier to turn the front wheels of a car (without power steering) when it's moving than when it's stationary?

How is this explained intuitively?

Answer (score 2):

When the car is standing still and you turn the steering wheel back and forth, you are slipping or *scrubbing* the rubber tire against the stationary road surface: performing work by abrading the tire as if by really rough sandpaper. In fact if you look at the road where you scrubbed it, you will see black tire dust rubbed into the road surface.

But when the car is rolling at speed, the tire surface is rolling against the pavement *almost without scrubbing*-that is, there is almost no *slippage* between them, and so very little rubber gets abraded off the tire. And when you turn the steering wheel at speed, the tire tracks off in the direction of the turn and the cornering forces are transmitted across the tire contact patch to the wheel through elastic deformation of the tire tread, without slippage- and hence, without abrasion work.

Note also that it is common to set up the steering geometry of the car's front end so that the contact patch is only slightly *behind* the steering pivot axis (this is called *caster*). Minimizing caster minimizes the effort required to turn the steering wheel. However, since caster also tends to make the car steer itself straight, a car with no caster exhibits *neutral stability* in a turn i.e., when set into a turn, the car exhibits no tendency to return to a straight line if you take your hands off the wheel- a dangerous condition.

As an aside, when going in *reverse*, the caster sense is backwards and the car will want badly to spontaneously turn itself into a full-lock steering condition, and go around and around in backwards circles. This is why people who leave their cars running without setting the car in park (or having the car's transmission "hop" out of the park position into reverse by itself) can be run over by their own car as it circles around and comes up behind them.

A design flaw in the transmission selector mechanism in Ford cars with automatic transmissions built in the mid-to-late 1960's caused then to sometimes hop out of park and drive themselves off in reverse, causing a number of such accidents.

Answer (score 0):

When the wheels roll without slipping, the point of contact of the wheels (with the road) remains stationary with respect to the road. **Only static friction acts** between the road the surface of the wheel in contact **so no energy is dissipated**. So turning the wheels take less energy as compared to when the car is stationary since when the car is stationary, the wheel actually slips on the surface of the road and some work is lost to overcome the forces of kinetic friction(due to slipping/rubbing) between the road and the surface of wheel in contact with the road.